# Pull and Run a Linux docker image on an azure pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When pulling and running a Linux docker based image in AZURE PIPELINE, I get this error: 
"image operating system "Linux" cannot be used on this platform"

1. I create a Linux docker image
2. I pushed the image to azure registry
3. I setup the azure pipeline as follow:

   - Docker CLI
   - Azure CLI:
   - I login to registry
   - Command Line:
   - I do: docker pull image
   - I do: docker run -it image

[image: Image showing Azure Pipeline]

When I run the pipeline, I get this error:
"image operating system "Linux" cannot be used on this platform"

Script output:

```
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4513990Z ##[section]Starting: Command Line Script
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4616971Z ==============================================================================
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4617284Z Task         : Command Line
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4617442Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4617592Z Version      : 2.146.1
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4617715Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-03-25T21:23:03.4618046Z ==============================================================================
2019-03-25T21:23:04.8241638Z Generating script.
2019-03-25T21:23:04.9020040Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\157d3a61-fe5f-46b2-b74e-1082d4532014.cmd""
2019-03-25T21:23:05.7814076Z v1: Pulling from hubb-api-tests
2019-03-25T21:23:06.2370457Z image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
2019-03-25T21:23:06.2872386Z the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
2019-03-25T21:23:06.3934386Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
2019-03-25T21:23:06.4549404Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

I expect to be able to pull the image and run it on Azure DevOps pipeline since I tested the same steps on my local computer with no problems.

Thank you so very much

[image: Image showing script output with error]

Comment: It seems you cannot run Linux image on windows platform. If you choose the windows web app to deploy the application?

Comment: @CharlesXu thanks for your comments. But would I still be able to run it in the pipeline after I deploy it?

Comment: Generally, Linux image can run in Windows host, it's ok if you run the Linux image in Windows VM. But it seems you cannot run Linux image on the windows service plan. Maybe you can try to select a Linux service plan.

Answer (score 6):

You can only achieve this using your own windows agent configured to allow to run linux containers on windows. hosted agents wont allow that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to set the hosted agent to ubuntu instead.
[image]